# Updated to Indy 130 packages from 120 and now this code does not work

Tags: delphi, sockets, http-post, delphi-2009

So this used to work without a hitch but now I get a "Socket Error #10054 Connection reset by peer."

I assume it started happening once I updated my Indy packages. Today was my first time running the code since then.

Can anyone explain how the update might have changed the behavior of this code And how to resolve it?

Thank You

```
function PostData(url : string; param: TStringList) : string;
var
  text: string;
  sHttpSocket: TIdHTTP;
  sshSocketHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  resStream: TStringStream;
begin
  sHttpSocket := TIdHTTP.create;
  sshSocketHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.create;
  sHttpSocket.IOHandler := sshSocketHandler;
  sHttpSocket.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  sHttpSocket.Request.Method := 'POST';
  resStream := TStringStream.create; 
  sHttpSocket.Post(url, param, resStream);
  resStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
  text := resStream.DataString;
  result := text;
end;
```

Comment: Indy routinely uses exceptions internally (IMO incorrectly, and that's one of the problems with using Indy). Are you seeing the exception when running outside the IDE? Usually the exceptions are properly handled at runtime, and only actually appear when running in the IDE where the debugger catches them. Also, you might indicate which line is actually triggering the exception, if it's happening outside the IDE (you can run it in the debugger, which will allow you to break on the line causing the exception when it happens).

Comment: It happens on this line sHttpSocket.Post(url, param, resStream);  I'll try running it outside the IDE.. thanks

Comment: It didin't work for me outside the IDE.. Maybe it's something temporarily down on their end..  But not sure.  What do you guys think?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check if Indy's redirect logic broke for you. That happens to me all the time. Check for a status 302 returned from the post method on shttpsocket.

Comment: Second idea; Try a newer version of the SSL dlls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are posting to an HTTPS url, make sure the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` is configured properly for the server you are trying to connect to.  Chances are, the defaults might not be matching up with what the server is actually expecting.  In particular, the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Method` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLVersions` properties default to TLSv1, but maybe the server does not support TLSv1.

On a side note, `TStringStream` operates differently in D2009+ than it did in earlier versions, so I would suggest you avoid it and let Indy decode the Text for you:

```
function PostData(const url : string; params: TStrings) : string; 
var 
  sHttpSocket: TIdHTTP; 
  sshSocketHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL; 
begin 
  sHttpSocket := TIdHTTP.Create; 
  try
    sshSocketHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(sHttpSocket); 
    // configure sshSocketHandler as needed...
    // perhaps try this at a minimum:
    // sshSocketHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    sHttpSocket.IOHandler := sshSocketHandler; 
    Result := sHttpSocket.Post(url, params); 
  finally
    sHttpSocket.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wow..  Thanks, setting the method to sslvSSLv23 did it!